# debian jessie logout automatically after login

Tags: linux, debian

Hi I have a problem with debian jessie one day ago I was use it. But this morning when I put my password appear a black screen and comeback the login, as if I had logged out.

Now I look for a detail about the problem but don't find nothing in .xsession-error where I can obtain information about this error or how I can fix it?

Comment: Isn't this just a manifestation of the screensaver being run and the seat (screen) locked automatically?  I'd say this feature is ubiquitous on contemporary graphical displays (Windows, Mac OS, GNOME etc)...

Comment: I remove the gdm3 and I find the problem is : “timeout in locking authority file /home/<user>/.Xauthority”